# Calculate total sum from multiple selections made + with base value

Tags: javascript, select, sum

This is basically for a product where product has multiple "**add ons**" like:
color
size
& etc

So these "**add ons**" are in select form field.
like:

```
color
<select class="cost">
<option value="0">Blue</option>
<option value="10">Red</option>
<option value="20">Pink</option>
</select>

size
<select class="cost">
<option value="0">small</option>
<option value="10">large</option>
<option value="20">x-large</option>
</select>
```

I want to display total of all selected add ons with product base price.

So here lets say product price is in hidden field as:

```
<input name="ProductPrice" value="100"/>
```

So if i selected color as red & size x-large so total will be 100+10+20= 130

I want to display just "130"

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to return array of `select` values and `reduce()` to return sum and add that to base price value. This solution is using jQuery.

```js
var base = $('input[name="ProductPrice"]').val();
$("select").change(function() {
  var addons = $('.cost').map(function() {
    return $(this).val()
  }).get().reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r + +e
  }, 0);

  $('input[name="ProductPrice"]').val(+base + addons)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
color
<select class="cost">
  <option value="0">Blue</option>
  <option value="10">Red</option>
  <option value="20">Pink</option>
</select> 
size
<select class="cost">
  <option value="0">small</option>
  <option value="10">large</option>
  <option value="20">x-large</option>
</select>

<input name="ProductPrice" value="100" />
```

This is pure javascript solution using `Array.from()` and `reduce()`.

```js
var base = document.querySelector('input[name="ProductPrice"]').value
var select = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select.cost'));

select.forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var sum = select.reduce(function(r, a) {
      return r + +a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
    }, 0);

    document.querySelector('input[name="ProductPrice"]').value = +base + sum;
  })
})
```

```html
color
<select class="cost">
  <option value="0">Blue</option>
  <option value="10">Red</option>
  <option value="20">Pink</option>
</select> 
size
<select class="cost">
  <option value="0">small</option>
  <option value="10">large</option>
  <option value="20">x-large</option>
</select>

<input name="ProductPrice" value="100" />
```

Comment: jquery version really works. But i m facing little issue cause the same i need to add to phpmyadmin. So i can't add "values"(price) into db but i need to add the ID of it, as these options are dynamic.

So i was thinking for calculation can it capture from <option name="100">

value="ID" value will be ID so.

Comment: @Webgen I am not sure what you mean, do you want to get `name` instead?

Comment: Currently all price gets added from option value="" i want price to be taken from name=""..
So select will be as follows:
<select class="cost">
<option value="ID123" name="0">small</option>
<option value="ID124" name="100">Large</option>

So for calculation i want "name" attribute to be used. not value

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe add a handler that calculate the values on change and adds them together.

```
$('select.cost').on('change', function () {
  var selectedValues = $('.cost');
  console.log(selectedValues);

   currentValue = parseInt($('#product-price').val());

   for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i += 1) {
       currentValue += parseInt($(selectedValues[i]).val());
   }

   $('#total-value').text(currentValue);

})
```

You can see the jsfiddlehere https://jsfiddle.net/3zon9zcc/

Comment: i like this one. but how can i display Product Base at first? on jsfiddle it displays only after selection is made.

Comment: You would just need to add the value to the total amount div

Comment: i want to display Product Base price before selection is made i.e Product Price.

If product price is 100 then after selection is made which adds 10 then total will be 110. Currently it shows nothing.. Total value is shown only when selection is made.

Comment: Also how to get the same value on hidden form field.

Comment: As I have said in the comment above you would need to add the value to the total amount div (or whatever I have called it in the fiddle) This will them show the value when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could add an `eventListener` and use a function for updating the price, while reding the selected index and applying the value of the options.

```js
document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', update);
document.getElementById('size').addEventListener('change', update);

function update() {
    var size = document.getElementById('size'),
        color = document.getElementById('color'),
        price = document.getElementById('price');

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = +price.value +
        +color.options[color.selectedIndex].value +
        +size.options[size.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="price" name="price" value="100" type="hidden" />
    <select class="cost" id="color" name="color">
        <option value="0">Blue</option>
        <option value="10">Red</option>
        <option value="20">Pink</option>
    </select>
    <select class="cost" id="size" name="size">
        <option value="0">small</option>
        <option value="10">large</option>
        <option value="20">x-large</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div>Price: <span id="total">100</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## A couple of options

Depending whether you want to dynamically track the number as it changes, or get it once on form submission, here are a couple of event options, calling the same function when triggered.

I've added `console.log()` and [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for the demonstration, but both can be removed for production. Preventing the default submission of a form can be useful in production code, but that's perhaps beyond the scope of this question.

**How it works**

[All of the `<select>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) are [collected in an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which is iterated by [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce an array of the values of each element. We then [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the result to add together all the values.

It is important to make sure that the [values are treated as integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), or they will be [concatenated as strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) instead.
I used a method (prepending the variable with the `+` operator) that is reliable in this context, but using `parseInt()` is arguably preferable.

We then add the result of reducing the array to the hidden input value (or put it wherever else you might want).

```js
const form = document.querySelector( "form" ),
      output = document.querySelector( "[type=hidden]" );

function outputCalculatedSelections() {
  output.value = Array.from( form.querySelectorAll( "select" ) ).map( ( s ) => {
    return s.value;
  } ).reduce( ( a, b ) => {
    return +a + +b; // use values as integers
  } );
  // for demonstration
  console.log( output.value );
}

// either of the below event listeners can be used.

// for dynamic calculation:
form.addEventListener( "change", outputCalculatedSelections, false );

// for one time calculation:
form.addEventListener( "submit", ( evt ) => {
  // for demonstration, prevent form submission:
  evt.preventDefault();
  outputCalculatedSelections();
}, false );
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Color: 
    <select class="cost">
      <option value="0">Blue</option>
      <option value="10">Red</option>
      <option value="20">Pink</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>Size: 
    <select class="cost">
      <option value="0">Small</option>
      <option value="10">Large</option>
      <option value="20">X-large</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```